# Why didn't my Capactive Wireless Power Transfer work?

Tags: electric-fields, capacitance, power

Today I had the delight of setting up a bipolar capactive wireless power transfer (CWPT) circuit for a school experiment. Disappointingly, it did not work.

It was set up just like in the diagram below: [image]

For $V_S$ I used a power supply at 12V AC 50Hz and the load was a multimeter. I did not have a rectifier, but as this is a proof of concept, I only really want to show a current, even if it is AC. I used 4 copper plates as the capacitors and they were ~2cm apart.

Can you please help me to identify what I can change to make this work? I will try using aluminum foil instead of copper as apparently it has better capacitance. Even with an ammeter that measured microamps, it returned nothing, despite having a reading when the metal plates were touched and not separated. Is it something to do with resonance and if so, how would I go about achieving it?

Comment: Have you done a basic circuit analysis to see if your design *should* work? Based on what you've written, particularly the frequency of the source and the way you built the capacitors, I would not expect the machine to work at all.

Comment: @DanielSank No, I was thinking mostly about the physics because in explanations I've seen, the AC current should make one plate negatively charged and one plate postively charged (on the TX) which will induce opposite charges on the RX plates, and when the current reverses, the charges on RX will swap which should be an electric current. I kindly implore you to explain any part that is wrong

Comment: For the analysis mentioned by @DanielSank I suggest that you estimate the capacitance of the capacitors and then look at [AC Capacitance Example No2](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/accircuits/ac-capacitance.html).

Comment: @Farcher I had a read and I think I see what you mean. With a low frequency and a tiny capacitance, is it that the capactive reactance is too large, preventing current flow? Excuse my naivety, but isn't the induced current on the RHS caused by the changing electric field which would only depend on the voltage applied between the two LHS plates. I see this setup as fundamentally different to what the tutorial site said, because there isn't really a circuit. The RHS plates could be powered by any changing electric field, which is so happened to be provided by the LHS. Please clarify, thanks :)

Comment: You have a series circuit composed of the power source, two capacitors and a resistor (the ammeter), To get a measurable current (mA?) you need to increase the capacitance of the capacitor (decrease separation of plates and insert dielectric eg thin plastic film which could also keep the plates separate), increase the frequency (and voltage) of the voltage source.  Aluminium foil might be better to use as it is flexible and will contour itself to the thin plastic film.

Comment: It does "work."  The only problem (!) is that making a guess at the area of your capacitor plates, the caps are about 1pF each, so the impedance of the circuit at 50Hz is of the order of 1Gohm. Unless your "microammeter" can display about 0.01uA, you won't see a reading.